# Values from a class instance's attribute being added to a different instance of the same class

Tags: python, pdfminer

I'm parsing pdfs to extract table data using my PdfTable class. When I create a class instance then create another class instance it seems that the first class instance file_1.cells are being prepended to the second class instance file_2.cells. I cannot figure out why this is happening as I don't think I'm creating class variables but only instance variables. For some reason the data from set_cells is persisted when another class instance is instantiated. What is happening?

```
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox, LTTextBoxHorizontal, LTTextLineHorizontal
from tabulate import tabulate
from utils import clean_string
from collections import namedtuple


class PdfTable(object):

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.table_headers = None
        self.cells = None
        self.rows = None

    def process_file(self, file_name):
        pages = []
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as fp:
            parser = PDFParser(fp)
            doc = PDFDocument(parser)
            rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
            laparams = LAParams()
            device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
            interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

            for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
                interpreter.process_page(page)
                pages.append(device.get_result())

        return pages

    def set_table_headers(self, page_obj, table_headers={}):
        values = ('NAME', 'VALUE', 'REFERENCE RANGE')
        Header = namedtuple('Header', 'name, x0, y0')

        for obj in page_obj:
            if isinstance(obj, LTTextLineHorizontal):
                text = clean_string(obj.get_text())
                if text in values:
                    table_headers[text] = Header(text, obj.bbox[0], obj.bbox[1])
            elif isinstance(obj, LTTextBoxHorizontal):
                self.set_table_headers(obj, table_headers)

        return table_headers

    def set_cells(self, page, headers, cells=[]):
        Cell = namedtuple("Cell", "col, text, x0, y0")
        col = None
        text = None

        for obj in page:
            if isinstance(obj, LTTextLineHorizontal):
                obj_x0 = obj.bbox[0]
                obj_y0 = obj.bbox[1]

                if obj_y0 < headers['NAME'].y0 and (obj_x0 == headers['NAME'].x0 or
                   obj_x0 == headers['VALUE'].x0 or obj_x0 == headers['REFERENCE RANGE'].x0):

                    if obj_x0 == headers['NAME'].x0:
                        col = 'NAME'
                    elif obj_x0 == headers['VALUE'].x0:
                        col = 'VALUE'
                    elif obj_x0 == headers['REFERENCE RANGE'].x0:
                        col = 'REFERENCE RANGE'

                    text = clean_string(obj.get_text())
                    if text:
                        cells.append(Cell(col, text, obj_x0, obj_y0))

            elif isinstance(obj, LTTextBoxHorizontal):
                self.set_cells(obj, headers, cells)

        return cells

    def set_rows(self, cells):
        Cell = namedtuple("Cell", "col, text, x0, y0")
        Row = namedtuple('Row', 'test, value, ref_range, y0')

        name_col = [cell for cell in cells if cell.col == 'NAME']
        value_col = [cell for cell in cells if cell.col == 'VALUE']
        ref_col = [cell for cell in cells if cell.col == 'REFERENCE RANGE']

        # normalize val col with blank cells to match name col length
        values_y0 = [cell.y0 for cell in value_col]
        missing_val_cells = [cell.y0 for cell in name_col if cell.y0 not in values_y0]
        value_col += [Cell('VALUE', None, None, y) for y in missing_val_cells]

        rows = [Row(name_cell.text, value_cell.text, ref_cell.text, name_cell.y0)
                for name_cell in name_col for value_cell in value_col
                for ref_cell in ref_col
                if name_cell.y0 == value_cell.y0 == ref_cell.y0]

        return rows

    def parse_pages(self):
        pages = self.process_file(self.file_name)
        self.set_metadata(pages[0])

        for page in pages:
            self.table_headers = self.set_table_headers(page)
            self.cells = self.set_cells(page, self.table_headers)

        self.rows = self.set_rows(self.cells)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_1 = PdfTable("RawData/pdfs/3768958-2.pdf")
    file_1.parse_pages()

    print("file_1 cells")
    print tabulate(file_1.cells, headers="keys", showindex="always")

    file_2 = PdfTable("RawData/pdfs/3768959.pdf")
    file_2.parse_pages()

    print("\nfile_2 cells")
    print tabulate(file_2.cells, headers="keys", showindex="always")
```

**file_1.cells**

```
    col              text                   x0       y0
--  ---------------  ---------------  --------  -------
 0  NAME             TP                42.8571  570.887
 1  NAME             RIN               42.8571  554.172
 2  VALUE            13.5             221.716   570.887
 3  VALUE            1.0              221.716   554.172
 4  REFERENCE RANGE  11.8-14.2 (SEC)  412.555   570.887
 5  REFERENCE RANGE  0.8-1.2          412.555   554.172
```

**file_2.cells**

```
    col              text                        x0       y0
--  ---------------  --------------------  --------  -------
 0  NAME             TP                     42.8571  570.887
 1  NAME             RIN                    42.8571  554.172
 2  VALUE            13.5                  221.716   570.887
 3  VALUE            1.0                   221.716   554.172
 4  REFERENCE RANGE  11.8-14.2 (SEC)       412.555   570.887
 5  REFERENCE RANGE  0.8-1.2               412.555   554.172
 6  NAME             RSW                    42.8571  570.887
 7  NAME             BCW                    42.8571  554.172
 8  VALUE            8.7                   221.716   570.887
 9  VALUE            25.6                  221.716   554.172
10  REFERENCE RANGE  4.5-12.5              412.555   570.887
11  REFERENCE RANGE  14.0-30.0             412.555   554.172
```

**expected file_2.cells**

```
    col              text                        x0       y0
--  ---------------  --------------------  --------  -------
 0  NAME             RSW                    42.8571  570.887
 1  NAME             BCW                    42.8571  554.172
 2  VALUE            8.7                   221.716   570.887
 3  VALUE            25.6                  221.716   554.172
 4  REFERENCE RANGE  4.5.-12.5             412.555   570.887
 5  REFERENCE RANGE  14.0-30.0             412.555   554.172
```

Not only are file_1.cells prepended to file_2.cells but after processing file_2, file_1.cells are the combination of cells from both instances.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, thank you for finding the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mutable default arguments `table_headers={}` and `cells=[]` which is probably the issue, or at least can cause other issues. These values are shared across calls to the methods so that changes in one call are reflected elsewhere.